# Java EE Web Application in IntelliJ with RichFaces

Tags: java, web-applications, intellij-idea, glassfish

I just created a new Java EE Web Application in IntelliJ with RichFaces (RichFaces files have been downloaded automatically to lib.

Now I edited the index.xhtml that it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
<f:view>

<h:head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <rich:panel header="Test">
        <h:outputText value="Content"/>
    </rich:panel>
</h:body>

</f:view>
</html>
```

Unfortunately in the browser only the word "Content" appears in plan text. So I can't see the RichFaces Panel. Do I have to include it manually?

Comment: Just so we're clear, exactly how are you loading this file in your browser? What app server are you using?

Comment: I installed glassfish via homebrew and configured the path in IntelliJ.

Comment: Ok, ok... Maybe tagging this question with "glassfish" would help, since it's more likely to be a glassfish problem than an IntelliJ one...? Now, you say "RichFaces files have been downloaded automatically to lib"... you mean the JARs, right? And that's the lib directory of your WAR/EAR? And you're sure they're in the deployed WAR/EAR in the app server?

Comment: The folder structure looks like this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2084506/Screen%20Shot%202016-01-04%20at%2019.04.51.png

Comment: Ok ... not familiar with IntelliJ specifically here, but it doesn't look to me as if the "lib" directory is being deployed ... I don't see it under `WEB-INF` in your exploded war directory...